# React Native, Performance between smartphone and android emulator

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm developing an app for andorid but different things happen between emulator and smartphone. When it refreshes a FlatList it does not respect the setTimout that I have imposed, consequently it does not refresh properly.

The app shows/delete images from a local database(react-native-local-mongodb) usign redux.
I'm a new entry in this "React and ES6 world" then I don't know a lot of right code(Promises or async-await for example).
I should do every things in reductor, but it fails then I invented this strange code.

This is the function that calls reductor

```
 deleteImages=()=>{
        Alert.alert(
            'Alert',
            'Are You sure to delete images?',
            [
                {text:'Yes, I am', onPress:()=>{
                    function start(){
                        setTimeout(del,1);
                        setTimeout(restoreDataFromDB,1000);
                        setTimeout(refState1,1500);
                        setTimeout(refState2,1550);
                    };
                    del=()=>{
                        //console.log('init_1');
                        this.props.onDeleteImages();
                    };
                    restoreDataFromDB=()=>{
                        //console.log('init_2.1');
                        let images=[];
                        db.loadDatabase(err=>{
                            db.find({_id:this.props.selectedPost},(erro,doc)=>{
                                doc.map((ele)=>{
                                    ele.imagesStored.map(elem=>{
                                        images.push(elem);
                                    });
                                });
                                this.setState({imagesStored:images});
                            });
                        });

                    };
                    refState1=()=>{
                        //console.log('init_3');
                        this.setState({refreshing:true,isChecked:false});

                    };
                    refState2=()=>{
                       // //console.log('init_4');
                        this.setState({refreshing:false});
                        this.componentDidMount();

                    };
                    try{
                        start();
                    }catch(err){
                       // //console.log('err: '+err);
                    }}
                },
                {text:'No I`m not',onPress:()=>{},style:'cancel'}
            ]);
    };
```

In the reductor delete images in the database and set new state,then after 1030ms returns in the first method to refresh data from database.

```
case DELETE_IMAGES:{
    let newImagesStored=[];
    var newData=[];
    function init(){
      setTimeout(copyImagesStored,1);
      setTimeout(updateImagesStoredState,50);//rispetta i tempi
      setTimeout(updateDB1,200);//rispetta il tempo
      setTimeout(updateDB2,300);//+50 per fare l'update perchè il conosole.log è dentro l'update...rispetta il tempo
      setTimeout(updateData,700);//rispetta il tempo
    };

    copyImagesStored=()=>{//copia le immaigni che devono restare in un array     
      //console.log('--1--') ;
      state.imagesStored.map((ele,index)=>{
        if(state.imagesSelected.includes(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ele)).id)){

        }else{
          newImagesStored.push(ele);
        }           
      });
      return state;
    };
    updateImagesStoredState=()=>{//modifica lo state con le nuove imagesStored
     // //console.log('--2--');
      return Object.assign(state,{imagesStored:newImagesStored},{imagesSelected:[]});
    };
    updateDB1=()=>{    //cancella tutte le immaigni dal post sul database  
      //console.log('state.imagesStored:'+state.imagesStored);  
      db.loadDatabase(err=>{
        db.update({_id:state.selectedPost},{$unset:{imagesStored:true}},{},()=>{
          //console.log('--3--');
        });
          return state;
      });
    };
    updateDB2=()=>{//inserisce le immaigni compiate nel db
      db.loadDatabase(err=>{
        db.update({_id:state.selectedPost},{$set:{'imagesStored':newImagesStored}},{},()=>{
         // //console.log('--4--') ;
        });
          return state;
      });
    };     
    updateData=()=>{//addiorna con un nuovo document lo stato
     // //console.log('--5--');
      state.data.map((ele,index)=>{//scorrendo t'array "data"
      //se l'id del post coincide con l'id dell'elemento del cursore
        if(state.selectedPost==JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ele))._id){
          let obj=JSON.stringify(ele);
          let parse=JSON.parse(obj);
          var newDoc={//crea un nuovo documento con le nuove immaigni
            year:parse.year,
            month:parse.month,
            day:parse.day,
            houre:parse.houre,
            minute:parse.minute,
            text:parse.text,
            imagesStored:newImagesStored
          };
          newData.push(newDoc);//inserisce il document ne nuovo array
        }else{
          newData.push(ele);//inserisce i dati da mantenere del nuovo array
        }
      });
      return Object.assign({},state,{data:newData});//aggiorna l'array "data" nello stato
    };
    try{
      init();
    }catch(err){
     // //console.log('err:'+err);
    }
    return state;
  }
```

I the emulator it works (save/delete/show images) correctly, but in the smartphone it doesn't delet images.

Comment: Are you running release or debug on the device?

Comment: I have tested the app in both debug and release versions. Maybe they are the "console.log" that slow down the app on the smartphone

Comment: using an approach with async await would be better?

Comment: I had a bug once when running release version on a device.. The `console.log` was preventing from the lines after it to run.

Comment: Yes, it's true, but now they are commented